# Empty results from analytics reporting api when requesting audience dimensions

Tags: google-analytics-api

I'm trying to get some GA metrics broken down over age bracket or gender, but the results come up empty.

If I try to break down sessions over browsers, I get results:

```js
{"reportRequests": [
 {"dimensions": [{"name": "ga:browser"}],
  "metrics": [{"expression": "ga:sessions"}],
  "viewId": "111459828"}]}
```

returns what I expect: a huge breakdown of the number of sessions per browser. When I request the age bracket dimensions, though:

```js
{"reportRequests": [
 {"dimensions": [{"name": "ga:userAgeBracket"}],
  "metrics": [{"expression": "ga:sessions"}],
  "viewId": "111459828"}]}
```

I get an empty result:

```js
{'reports': [
  {'columnHeader': {'dimensions': ['ga:userAgeBracket'],
                    'metricHeader': {'metricHeaderEntries': [
                                     {'name': 'ga:sessions',
                                      'type': 'INTEGER'}]}},
   'data': {'totals': [{'values': ['0']}]}}]}
```

The same happens for `ga:userGender` and whether I pass `includeEmptyRows` or not. My OAuth scope is `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics`, as I think it's supposed to be and i'm using v4 of the API. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please post the full json request you are making.

Comment: What do you mean 'full request?' The body in my question is all i pass to the client: in python: `body = <what's in the question>` and then `service.reports().batchGet(body=body).execute()`

Comment: If that's the only json you are sending then I would have expected an error and not nothing.   Please post all of your python code.

Comment: You do have demographic and interest reports enabled on your account right?   https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2819948

Comment: It is enabled, but apparently I also still have to enable Advertising Features (can't do this myself as I'm not an admin on the account). Could this be the reason?

Comment: test it here if it doesn't work you know you probably have no data https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/  (Note that's V3)